# How does multiplication work with 16 bit register in Assembly - MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

According to my textbook, ax equals FE01h:

```
mov al, -1
mov bl, -1
mul b1
```

How is this the case? The textbook does not explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your operation `mul` is [defined](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html) as:

```
ax = (unsigned)al * (unsigned)bl
```

`-1` is converted to unsigned, which is `255` (check out [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement))

so, as soon as `al = 255` and `bl = 255`, result is `ax = 65025` (`FE01` in hex)

Comment: Wouldn't it be 0001?

Comment: How did you get 255?